# Xcode 6 fixed View in Table View Controller

Tags: swift, view, ios8, xcode6, tableview

Good day, everyone.

I've got a Table View Controller with an View on top as a header.
My problem is, that if I scroll in the Table View, the View scrolls with it. How can I fix the header (View), so it stops scrolling with the table view?
I was searching like crazy, but didn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

I am using XCode 6 (iOS8 and Swift)

Comment: Any storyboard & structure ? too abstract to think of it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done. It's the default behavior of the tableViewController. You have two solution as I believe. One is to edit the content offset and ad a subview on the tableView itself. Or just change it to a view controller and add a table view as a subview and your view.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me from hours of searching.

Comment: I am glad that it did help you. :)